# MS Access VBA, efficient way to enable a button only after all required textboxes contains valid data

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

My code is working, but I just want to know if there is a more efficient way to achieve the same effect.

I have this layout in a form:

[image: Form Layout]

In my effort to foolproof the record creation process, I would like to have the "Save and Clear fields" button enabled only after all but the 'Comment' textbox/combobox contains some valid data.

The text/combo boxes are called txtBatteryID, cmbModelNumber, cmbChemistryType, txtSpecVoltage, txtSpecCapacity.

My code is as follow

```
Private Sub EnableSaveBtnCheck()
'this checks if the required fields contains valid data, if so, enables the save button.
    If Me.btnSaveAndCLear.Enabled = False Then
        If IsNull(txtBatteryID) = False And IsNull(cmbModelNumber) = False And IsNull(cmbChemistryType) = False And IsNull(txtSpecVoltage) = False And IsNull(txtSpecCapacity) = False Then
            Me.btnSaveAndCLear.Enabled = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

As you can see, I did the most straightforward way of using AND to combine all must-have conditions in an IF statement. This sub is called in After_Update() event of each text/combo box. Like this:

```
Private Sub cmbChemistryType_AfterUpdate()
    Call EnableSaveBtnCheck
End Sub
```

My question, in the end, is: Is there a more efficient way to setup the condition "all text/combo box need to have something valid in them"? And is there a more elaborate way to check if the condition is met (something  like a event on the form itself)?

Comment: Looks efficient enough to me. Why would you want 'more elaborate'? And no, I don't think there is a form event that could accommodate.

Comment: just out of curiosity. never know when there would be a case where one have to check for a lot more conditions. lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the values of those 5 fields. If any of them is Null, the sum will be Null. So you only need call `IsNull()` once.

```
If IsNull(txtBatteryID + cmbModelNumber + cmbChemistryType + txtSpecVoltage + txtSpecCapacity) = False Then
```

Comment: And I should have remembered it. Nice.

Comment: Hmm. I tried this on my file, there is a type mismatch (I have numbers and texts). I'm sure this works when everything is the same type. I will see if I can change the data type of those variables in the statement to make it work.